# How to check if a TypeError is for NoneType

Tags: python, exception

I am testing some code I have written, and when functioning normally, it could raise a TypeError of the variety where *'NoneType' object is not iterable*. Since this expected, I would like to deal with this as it happens, without inadvertently hiding other TypeErrors.

How can I test if my TypeError is for *'NoneType'*, and not for other reasons? I have looked at the attributes of the TypeError but can't seem to understand which would tell me the cause for the error.

Comment: One option would be to check if the item is `None` before iterating rather than using `try/except`. Another along the same lines would be `for item in items or []`.

Comment: Sometimes, in these kind of situations, you can make a small design change so that you will have an an empty tuple (or other empty collection) in place of `None`.  Check first if you can do that, it's usually more elegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're essentially trying to check for `None` types since the error you're receiving indicates directly that you're trying to iterate over some variable that is `None`. I'd use the classic python check for `None` to determine when that is the case:

```
if my_iterable_collection is None:
    ... no good
else:
    ... we're good
```

This is how I'd try and find and bubble up `None` related issues, rather than using `try/catch`. You'll know the exact error is related to `None` with a high degree of granularity.

Comment: why not `if result is None:` ?

Comment: Mistake on my part, I agree, it's been changed! Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre